# Setting Two Indexes In One Database Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I'm using MySQL but this question is not specific to that particular database.
I have `posts` table, and `threads` table.
Nothing complicated  and of course within `posts` I have *thread_id* column which ties posts to a thread that owns them.
I want to have foreign key constraint on that column (*thread_id* in `posts` table), something like:

```
  CONSTRAINT `thread_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So the question is, how smart it is, or not, to also have a second index on that *thread_id* column?
Like this:

```
KEY `thread_idx` (`thread_id`)
```

or:

```
 INDEX `thread_idx` (`thread_id`)
```

Will FOREIGN KEY index on it's own speed things up when selecting, making second index redundant, or second index is necessary for faster selects, or having two indexes on one column is bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which RDBMS you are using, but in general a Foreign key will not create an Index. It is considered a good practice to create an index for the columns involved in the Foreign key.

But you should also consider the query/ies that you are trying to optimize by creating this index/es. Having multiple indexes containing the same column is not necessarily a bad.

Comment: That is what I basically wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: Another wasteful thing:  If you have both `INDEX(a,b)` and `INDEX(a)` -- the latter is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes.The first index should have already set up a reference order of the data based on the order of "a" so the second Index is not required, the optimizer can utilize the first index for both purposes. But if you had `Index(b,a)` and `Index(a)` then it would provide performance gains to have both.